# Best way to saving completed progress in table?

Tags: lua

So, i have empty table.

```
local data_tbl = {}
```

But i need save data when user complete current task.
Like:

```
-- (1, 2, 21) it's task id.
data_tbl['1'] = true 
data_tbl['2'] = true
data_tbl['21'] = true
```

And in table "data_tbl" it's look like

```
data_tbl {
1 = true,
2 = true,
21 = true,
}
```

I wan't saving only completed task. Not all , because it's very heavy ?
But when i wanted remove this key , like 21 , i'ts get nothing effect.

```
table.remove(data_tbl, 21)
```

Task with 21 index not removed. Why ?
Maybe have other best way for all this ? (Saving complete tasks)

I don't want use table.Add() because it's added to last position. Like `table.Add(data_tbl, {completed_id = 21})`
And in table it's look like.

```
data_tbl {
1 = {completed_id = 21}
}
-- It's get me more table checks... and cycles , i don't want.
```

Comment: I take it there is some other code that prevents you just setting 21 to `false` and checking if it's true when you need it?

Comment: @Taazar I don't want stacking false values in data table. I only want have true value or nothing if false.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case setting the values to `nil` as Darius and DarkWiiPlayer have said will achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`table.insert` and `table.remove` are meant for sequences, but you're using the table as a map. If you have a key, say `21` and want to unset it, just do `data_tbl[21] = nil`

Answer (score 2):

lua tables are hash tables, to insert data to table use `mytable[name] = value` or `mytable.myname = value`, to remove from table `mytable[name] = nil` or `mytable.myname = nil`.

To simulate arrays lua tables has helper functions in module `table` and some sort of optimizations, but id's must be numbers and begin with 1.

For mixed tables like `mytable[1] = true; mytable[2] = true; mytable[3] = true; mytable[21] = true; mytable.name = 'values'`, `#mytable` evaluates to length of 3 as entries [21] and 'name' do not form the sequence.

`table.remove` and `table.insert` modifies 'array' shifting corresponding elements:

```lua
local mytable = {1, 2, 3, 4}

table.remove(mytable, 2)
print(table.concat(mytable, ',')) -- result is {1, 3, 4 }

table.insert(mytable, 2, 5)
print(table.concat(mytable, ',')) -- result is {1, 5, 3, 4 }
```

Numeric strings as keys will be not converted internally into numbers (like in javascript) and will not work with array like methods:

```lua
local mytable = {}
mytable[21] = 'value21'
mytable['21'] = 'string21'

-- table content: {[21] = 'value21', ['21'] = 'string21'}
```

Comment: I checked now , test[1] = true , test[3] = true, and after i use table.remove( test, 3 ), it's got nothing effect. Why ? After all, now keys is numbers.

Comment: Module `table` is for use with array like tables - list starting with 1 without gaps. You use table as hash/named table so you must remove with `test[3] = nil`